# CSS glow(shadow?) with transition doesn't completely work

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, css-transitions

This is kind of specific, so it is very difficult to choose a correct title or try to find an already existing fix, but here it is, anyway:

I found this code snippet on the web when I was searching for something similar and decided to use it on the project I am working on:

```
.text-glow:hover, .text-glow:focus, .text-glow:active {
   -webkit-stroke-width: 5.3px;
   -webkit-stroke-color: #FFFFFF;
   -webkit-fill-color: #FFFFFF;
   text-shadow: 1px 0px 20px yellow;
   -webkit-transition: width 0.3s; /*Safari & Chrome*/
   transition: width 0.3s;
   -moz-transition: width 0.3s; /* Firefox 4 */
   -o-transition: width 0.3s; /* Opera */
   }
.text-glow a {
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in; /*Safari & Chrome*/
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in; /* Firefox 4 */
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in; /* Opera */
   text-decoration:none;
   color:white;
   }
```

It adds a "glow" to the text using pure CSS.
The problem is, I'm not very fluent in the newer things in CSS3, thus, although I use this snippet(is that what it's even called?), I only really vaguely understand how it works.

So, it works fine as long as I add an empty link to the text—`<a href="#">Text</a>`—while surrounding it with `<span class="text-glow"></span>`, but if I use this on a link that actually redirects somewhere(home page), the slow transition of the glow spreading/fading in while I hover my mouse over it doesn't work. It's simply there, although it does fade out normally.

[Here is the JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gdc4a1bj/1/) Hover over the text that says "Doesn't Work" and you'll see what I mean.

It would be great if you guys can help me fix this—preferably using nothing but CSS, if not possible then Javascript's okay, but please not jQuery, don't know much of that yet—and if possible, explain how this works in a bit of a "quasi-newbie" language.

Comment: Fiddle works for me (chrome v43.0, firefox v38.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using the class "umn" on both the link and it's parent.

Change it from

```
<span class="unm"><a href="index.html" class="unm">Doesn't Work</a></span>
```

to

```
<span class="unm"><a href="index.html">Doesn't Work</a></span>
```

and it will work. See my updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yd8tpkw5/